# Can tone that a sentence is said turn it into a question?

Tags: grammar-identification, question

Say you want to ask your friend if they want to eat, you could say

> You want to eat?

Or,

> Do you want to eat?

The first sentence, in speaking, sounds like a declarative sentence, but it has an interrogative meaning. I believe a similar phenomena happens in Arabic. Does this also hold in German?

As in, would

> Du willst essen?

be same as,

> Willst du essen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Raising the pitch on the last word marks a sentence a question in German.

Be aware that this only applies to the last word. If you raise the pitch on another word, this word is in **standout** in German. It's sometimes use in speech to mark a contradiction, or where English speakers would use their hands to write quotes in the air.

Comment: what is this phenomena called?

Comment: Rising intonation.

Comment: Btw.: This works also in English: One of two young women to the bouncer of a club: "Let her in too. She is 18." (Note, that "She is 18" is clearly a statement here.) Bouncer: "Oh really? She is 18?" instead of "Is she 18?" The sentence "Is she 18?" has the word order of a question, while "She is 18?" has the word order of a statement, but still it's semantically a question, and this comes only from the tone: The pitch of the last syllable is higher than the pitch of the syllable before, and this pattern of intonation turns every statement into a question.